# Joining two tables and returning multiple records as one row using LINQ

Tags: linq, join

I'm trying to write a LINQ expression that will join two tables and return data in a format similar to what is possible using MySql's GROUP_CONCAT. I tried searching around on Google and SO, but all the results I found used MSSQL or were only using one table. The expression I have written now looks like this:

```
from d in division
join o in office on d.Id = o.DivisionId
select new
{
    id = d.Id,
    cell = new string[] { d.DivisionName, o.OfficeName }
}
```

As expected, this returns a list of every division and what offices correspond to that division. The only problem is that since most divisions will have more than one office, I get a division back for each office in said division. Essentially I'm seeing results like this:

```
Division1: Office1
Division1: Office2
Division1: Office3
Division2: Office1
```

When I want to see:

```
Division1: Office1, Office2, Office3
Division2: Office1
```

I remember doing something a while ago with MySql that used GROUP_CONCAT, but I can't figure out what the equivalent of that would be using LINQ. I tried writing a method which had an `IEnumerable<Office>` parameter and built a string using the `Aggregate` extension method, but the way I have my LINQ expression written now, each Office is passed in rather than an `IEnumerable<Office>`. Is there a better way to approach this problem than what I'm doing now? I'm rather new to LINQ expressions, so I apologize if this is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a *group join*, e.g.

```
from d in division
join o in office on d.Id = o.DivisionId into offices
select new
{
    id = d.Id,
    divisionName = d.DivisionName,
    officeNames = offices.Select(o => o.OfficeName)
}
```

Comment: This works wonderfully in LINQ Pad. It works in my code as well, but instead of returning the actual OfficeName, it returns a `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`. I think that's an error on my end in how I'm handling the values returned from the LINQ expression.

Comment: @Zajn: You might want to use `officeNames = offices.Select(o => o.OfficeName).ToList()` or something like that - it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're doing. Iterating over the office names should work anyway though.